# Uploading images using Froala WYSIWYG Editor and save that into the ActiveStorage in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wysiwyg, froala

I am new to ruby on rails. I am recently playing with Froala WYSIWYG Editor and I am wondering if it is possible to store the image into ActiveStorage that I have opened from Froala WYSIWYG Editor.

```
<%= nested_form_for @student do |form| %>
 <div class="field">
  <%= form.label :profile_picture %>
  <%= form.text_field :profile_picture %>
 </div>    

<div class="field">
 <%= form.label :content %>
 <%= form.text_area :content, id: "wysiwyg"%>
</div>

 <%= form.submit %>
<%end%>

<script>
 $('#wysiwyg').froalaEditor({
  heightMin: '300px'
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Technically, yes.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62621054/how-to-upload-a-file-from-froala-editor-to-rails-active-storage/67671987